# Does this code follow duck typing?

Tags: python, dynamic-typing, python-3.x, duck-typing, dynamic-languages

> The principle of duck typing says that you shouldn't care what type of object you have - just whether or not you can do the required **action** with your **object**. For this reason the `isinstance` keyword is frowned upon. - -[Definition](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/duck_typing.shtml)

In below snippet(function) `group_tweets_by_state`, following definition of duck typing, action `setdefault` is performed on the object `tweets_by_state` by appending object `tweet`

```
def group_tweets_by_state(tweets):
    tweets_by_state = {}
    USA_states_center_position = {n: find_center(s) for n, s in us_states.items()}
    for tweet in tweets:                     # tweets are list of dictionaries 
        if hassattr(tweet, 'setdefault'):    # tweet is a dictionary 
            state_name_key = find_closest_state(tweet, USA_states_center_position)
            tweets_by_state.setdefault(state_name_key, []).append(tweet)
    return tweets_by_state
```

My understanding is, function `hasattr(tweet, 'setdefault')` is type checking `tweet` to be of `<class 'dict'>` type in duck typing style, **before** append.

Is my understanding correct? Does function `group_tweets_by_state` follow duck typing?

Comment: I have no idea what "does function _x_ smell duck typing" means. Functions do not have a sense of smell.

Comment: Anyway it's daft to check for the existence of `setdefault` if you're not going to use it. If you want to know whether it's a dict, use `isinstance`, that's what it's for.

Comment: Using `isinstance`  is not duck typing.

Comment: No, but this is just doing isinstance in another way, it's the same thing. Duck typing would be to just assume that it is a dict, and if that throws an exception, well then so be it. Should have passed something that wouldn't throw an exception.

Comment: Duck typing simply means that in your functions you expect objects to follow certain protocol and you don't care about the type. Here, you expect that `tweets` is iterable and that its elements behave as dicts. They need not be `dict`s, they can be `OrderedDict`s for all you care.

Comment: Does STL algorithms in C++ follow similar technique?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A test like `hassattr(tweet, 'setdefault')` to make sure `tweet` is a dictionary is not a good one, since it obviously does not assure `tweet` provides all methods/properties of a dictionary. So as long `tweet.setdefault` is not the only method called by `find_closest_state` (which I think is unlikely), this test is not strict enough. On the other hand, a test like `isinstance(tweet, dict)` is too strict, because it forbids the usage of other, dictionary-like structures, which is exactly the idea of duck typing.

In your example the requirement is not really that `tweet` is a dictionary, the requirement is that `find_closest_state` can process the tweet, whatever methods it calls from a tweet, independently of the real type. The following solution will handle this in a generic manner, without the need of knowing exactly what methods inside `find_closest_state` are used:

```
def group_tweets_by_state(tweets):
    tweets_by_state = {}
    USA_states_center_position = {n: find_center(s) for n, s in us_states.items()}
    for tweet in tweets:              # a  tweet should behave like a dictionary
        try: 
            state_name_key = find_closest_state(tweet, USA_states_center_position)
            tweets_by_state.setdefault(state_name_key, []).append(tweet)
        except (AttributeError, TypeError):
            pass
    return tweets_by_state
```

The code checks for an `AttributeError` because that is the exception you get when `find_closest_state` calls a method not provided by `tweet`. It also checks for a `TypeError`, because that is what you get when you call `tweet["abc"]` on a non-dictionary. You may need to add some other exceptions, depending on how `find_closest_state` is implemented internally, but you should not add any artificial constraints.

And that's how duck typing should really be applied - by not making assumptions about the type of the object passed, only by testing whether or not you can do the required action (here: call `find_closest_state` without getting one of the above exceptions).

Answer (score 4):

First, I want to say that by far not everybody agrees that duck typing is a good thing at all, let alone that it is some sort of holy principle that should be followed. Often duck typing leads to error prone, hard to debug code, although it can be very flexible in how you can use it.

Duck typing just takes an object and does with the object what it wants to do E.g. if it expects an open file object that it wants to call `.write()` on, then it just does that. If that throws an exception because the object doesn't have that method, then you passed in a non-duck. Your fault. If you passed in a completely different kind of object that also works because it has a `.write()`, that is the benefit of duck typing.

So your code would use "duck typing" if it simply assumes that `tweets` is a list of dictionaries (like the comment says), and doesn't go to any trouble to check that.

```
def group_tweets_by_state(tweets):
    tweets_by_state = {}
    USA_states_center_position = {n: find_center(s) for n, s in us_states.items()}
    for tweet in tweets:                     # tweets are list of dictionaries 
        state_name_key = find_closest_state(tweet, USA_states_center_position)
        tweets_by_state.setdefault(state_name_key, []).append(tweet)
    return tweets_by_state
```

Comment: The problem here is that some of the tweets maybe dictionaries, others not, and the original code tried to handle this *without* throwing an exception, just by skipping the non-dictionaries. That is not what your supposed solution does any more.

Comment: I know that may be the case, but I'm not sure because of his "# tweets are lists of dictionaries" comment. I don't think changing the functionality is by itself a problem, one would expect that a function might do something slightly different if it uses duck typing compared to one that  doesn't . And having lists with different kinds of things in them is not a good fit for the duck typing style of writing functions, I think.

Comment: To rephrase that, without knowing more than we do about his data or `find_closest_state`, I think using `isinstance` and forgetting about duck typing is the way to go. Surely using a bare `except:` like in your answer has its issues too.

Comment: There is no bare `except` in my answer any more, maybe you missed my edit?.

Comment: I did, but now it's the other problem: we have no way of knowing whether it will raise AttributeError. But I'll grant that it does the same thing as the original now.

Comment: an AttributeError will be raised if someone calls a non-existing method of an object (I tested it). You are correct, there could other things go wrong, and maybe different exceptions to be handled. But the gist of my answer is to demonstrate how to avoid `isinstance`, so the code will perfectly work with anything which "looks like a duck (sorry, `dict`)", and not only with dictionaries.